# applying unique primary keys to each custom-defined group within a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
DAYS7 <- c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')   
DAYS <- rep(DAYS7, 3, each = 3)
BIN <- c('00_07', '07_18', '18_24')
BIN <- rep(BIN, 21)
A <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
B <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
DESIRED_OUTPUT <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
dataframe <- as.data.frame(cbind(DAYS, BIN, A, B, DESIRED_OUTPUT))  
dataframe$DAYS <- as.character(dataframe$DAYS)
dataframe$A <- as.numeric(as.character(dataframe$A))
dataframe$B <- as.numeric(as.character(dataframe$B))
dataframe$DESIRED_OUTPUT <- as.numeric(as.character(dataframe$DESIRED_OUTPUT))
```

*Column BIN* has 3 outputs: **00_07, 07_18, 18_24.** (The underlying idea is that I'm analyzing financial data. Using this bin, I can see what portion of the transactions took place in a certain time interval within a day - whether it be the morning hours **(between 0:00 and 7:00)**, daytime **(between 7:00 and 18:00)** or evening hours **(between 18:00 and 24:00.)**

If it's a working day, the corresponding cell in *column A* equals zero. If it is holiday, *column A* shows 1.

*Column B* is essentially the same as *column A*, except it adds leading and trailing 1s to each weekend, hence all Friday evenings (18:00-24:00) and Monday mornings (00:00-07:00) will also be labelled as 1.

Now here comes the tricky part. I would like to apply unique primary keys to each of these custom-defined groups defined in *column B*. So what I have in mind is something like this (see column *DESIRED_OUTPUT*).

[image]

Do you have any suggestions how to approach this problem in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R.  Requires data to be sorted.

```
dataframe$PK <- cumsum(diff(c(0, dataframe$B)) == 1) * dataframe$B
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rle` :

```
with(rle(dataframe$B), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths))
```